# Icon for clearing ALL values in form

Tags: icon, interface-design, symbolism

What icon should I use for **clearing all values** from textboxes, selectors etc in my form on aspx website.

I don't want to use the reload button icon, because I'm not going to do postback I will just clear all the values. I've seen icon like brush to indicate cleaning but I don't think that indicates that it will clear all.

I want to make sure to indicate that it will clear all the text boxes etc in my form not just one.

Is it possible to do this without adding a text "ALL"?

Comment: I don't think you can. There will always be people who'll interpret it differently. I'd opt for a modal, asking the user to confirm whether or not to really clear **all** values. Alternatively, an _undo clear all_ is also a good option for those who are caught by surprise.

Answer (score 1):

How about some sort of cleaning device?

- A sponge
- A window cleaning thing (squeegee)
- A car frontwindow cleaning thing
- A eraser

or my favorite:

- A Skull with crossed bones ;)

Comment: I think the skull might make some people scared about what's going to happen :D...

Comment: The thing is is there some symbol that lets you know that the CLEANing device will be applied on whole form(it's like 10 things-mostly textboxes- to be filled)

Comment: What? I don't understand your comment. Do you have some screenshots?

Comment: https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=erase&i=3626 its called a squeegee

Comment: What an awesome word :)

Answer (score 1):

The [Noun project](https://thenounproject.com/) can give you ideas. Here are some ideas

[image][image]

**Image 1-2**: Search for [Erase](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=erase), by  Chris Robinson and [Dan Hetteix](http://www.hetteix.com/)

[image][image]

**Image 3-4**: Search for [Clear](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=clear), by  [Ilsur Aptukov](http://aptukov.ru/).  Search for [Empty](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=empty) by  [Sergey Demushkin](http://owlstories.tumblr.com/).

I'm sure you can get more ideas by searching yourself. You can combine ideas, for example clipboard with a eraser symbol etc.

Comment: Thanks this http://i.stack.imgur.com/j9Hek.png actually is something what I had in my mind, I just didn't know how to symbolise the whole(everything/all in) form >.<

Comment: @Ms.Nobody I think it symbolizes the whole thing well. If i needed to be more *explicit* I would combine eraser with clipboard with text on it and then let the erase intersect all lines.